# How to sort a structured list of stock data for later access in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, stocks, yahoo-api

I am very new to Python and want to build a black box stock trading program that finds various correlations between stock's rates of return and gives me a response such as buy, sell, hold, etc. I found a neat little easy to use Python module for retrieving stock data called ystockquote that pulls information from Yahoo! Finance. The module can be found at http://www.goldb.org/ystockquote.html.

One of its abilities is to output historical prices for a stock in the form `['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Clos']`. I can give it a date range to do this and it gives me a nested list containing a single list with the above information this for each day.

My question is how to organize each of these separate data points (Date, Open, High, Low, etc.) into a structure that I can call upon later in my script and sort. I need this process to be easy to automate. What sorts of algorithms or data structures might I find useful?

Comment: It is easy to sort a list or a dictionary in python. But you have to be more specific, so we can be more specific. You are not asking about how to sort a list, are you?

Comment: You need to write yourself a `cmp` function which is an optional parameter in the sort function, which you can see if you do `help([].sort)`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this so I didn't think to include that this all needs to be automated before I edited it recently. To clarify I need code or a method that will take the output data from the ystockquote module and automatically sorts it into a dictionary like configuration so that I can call on each value (for example a specific dates's close price) from each day and receive a purely numeric response. So if on May 1st 2011 a stock is at $20.87 when I call on that I can get $20.87 as a response.

Comment: Good clarification, but I think you can figure out how to do that bit on your own. I've got you 99% of the way... see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) structure rather than a list:

```
>>> prices = dict()
>>> prices['2011-01-02'] = {'Open':20.00, 'High':30.00, 'Low':10.00, 'Close':21.00, 'Volume':14.00, 'Adj Clos':120}
>>> prices['2010-11-09'] = {'Open':22.00, 'High':50.00, 'Low':20.00, 'Close':42.00, 'Volume':10.00, 'Adj Clos':666}
>>> prices
{'2011-01-02': {'Volume': 14.0, 'Adj Clos': 120, 'High': 30.0, 'Low': 10.0, 'Close': 21.0, 'Open': 20.0}, '2010-11-09': {'Volume': 10.0, 'Adj Clos': 666, 'High': 50.0, 'Low': 20.0, 'Close': 42.0, 'Open': 22.0}}
```

Here I've nested a dictionary within each entry of the main "prices" dictionary. The first level of the dictionary takes the date as its key, and maps to a dictionary containing the price information for that date.

```
>>> prices['2011-01-02']
{'Volume': 14.0, 'Adj Clos': 120, 'High': 30.0, 'Low': 10.0, 'Close': 21.0, 'Open': 20.0}
```

The second level of the dictionary uses the attribute names as keys, and maps to the attribute values themselves.

```
>>> prices['2010-11-09']['Open']
22.0
>>> prices['2010-11-09']['Close']
42.0
```

It seems that, for the `get_historical_prices` function you refer to, each day is output as an entry of the form `[Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj_Clos]`. If you want to construct a dictionary for a list of these entries, you're gonna need to do three things:

First, you'll need to index each entry to separate out the `Date` from the other elements, since that is what you'll be using to index the first dimension of your dict. You can get the first element with `entry[0]` and the remaining elements with `entry[1:]`.

```
>>> entry = ['2011-01-02', 20.00, 30.00, 10.00, 21.00, 14.00, 120]
>>> date = entry[0]
>>> date
'2011-01-02'
>>> values = entry[1:]
>>> values
[20.0, 30.0, 10.0, 21.0, 14.0, 120]
```

Second since you want to associate each of the other elements with a specific key, you should make a list of those keys in the same order as the data elements are given to you. Using the `zip()` function you can combine two lists `p` and `q`, taking the ith element from each and making `zip(p,q)[i] == (p[i], q[i])`. In such a way you create a list of (key, value) pairs that you can pass to a dictionary constructor:

```
>>> keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Clos']
>>> pairs = zip(keys, entry[1:])
>>> pairs
[('Open', 20.0), ('High', 30.0), ('Low', 10.0), ('Close', 21.0), ('Volume', 14.0), ('Adj Clos', 120)]
```

Finally you want to construct your dictionary, and index it into its appropriate date in the overall history:

```
>>> stockdict = dict(pairs)
>>> stockdict
{'Volume': 14.0, 'Adj Clos': 120, 'High': 30.0, 'Low': 10.0, 'Close': 21.0, 'Open': 20.0}
>>> histodict = dict()
>>> histodict[date] = stockdict
```

You can iterate through your nested `history` list to construct your dictionary in two ways, the first is using a traditional `for` loop:

```
keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Clos']
histodict = dict()
for item in history:
    date = item[0]
    values = item[1:]
    histodict[date] = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Or if you want to play around with a slightly more advanced Python technique, try a nested dict [generator statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
keys = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Clos']
histodict = dict((item[0], dict(zip(keys, item[1:]))) for item in history)
```

That last one's a doozy if you're new to programming, but I encourage you to read up in that link; remember, when programming in Python, Google is your friend. I hope I've given you sufficient keywords and ideas here to get started learning, and I'll leave the rest up to you.

Comment: This is what I need but how do I automate it with my output data from ystockquote so I don't have to configure an entry manually for every single date?

Comment: After some tinkering I figured out how to use this code the way I wanted. Thanks so much! You were a huge help and you made a great contribution to my learning.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of lists of equal length, its very easy to sort by any "column":

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda l: l[1])
>>> l
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda l: l[4])
>>> l
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

The `key` keyword argument takes a function that, given an item in the list, returns a value which is used as the sort key.

But if you want to do more interesting things, you're probably better off using a database. Conveniently (for me), the [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) docs use a table of stocks as an example, which I have appropriated and modified gently:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/example')   # use ':memory:' for an in-memory db
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''create table stocks
(date text, trans text, symbol text,
 qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("""insert into stocks
          values ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)""")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# Insert another row of data
c.execute("""insert into stocks
          values ('2006-01-07','SELL','RHAT',100,2.11)""")

# Select rows of data from table in an order
rows_by_date = c.execute("""select * from stocks order by date""")
for row in rows_by_date:
    print row

# In a different order
rows_by_price = c.execute("""select * from stocks order by price""")
for row in rows_by_price:
    print row
```

Comment: There is a [step-by-step](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Securities-Master-Database-with-MySQL-and-Python) tutorial written by Michael Halls-Moore  on how to setp-up a securities master database using MySQL, [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). I found it extremely clear and simple.